# How do I configure SonarQube to display all modules of a multi-module maven project?

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I have a multi-module maven project with a structure like

```
parent
 - child1
 - child2
 - child3
```

In the SonarQube dashboard I can only see the parent project. If I search for "child1" in the "Search for projects, sub-projects and files..." box I am able to find and view each child module.

Is there any possibility to have these sub-projects displayed at the dashboard or at least be able to navigate to them without doing a search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can browse the code of your project by clicking on the "code" tab.
See this example on SonarCloud : https://sonarcloud.io/code?id=com.cognifide.aemrules%3Aaemrules

Comment: Hi Julien, can you take a look at this question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/57574433/2877029

I don't think many people are subscribed to `sonar` tag, so since you are in Sonar-team, you might have something to say there