# SonarQube multi-module and multi-sub-folder project configuration

Tags: sonarqube, sbt, static-analysis

I have a multi-module `sbt` project with the following structure:

```
parent/
 child1/
   src/
 group/
   child1/
     src/
   child2/
     src/
```

I need to configure SonarQube to scan all of the modules in (possibly) nested folders.

*Note:* I have `child1` and `group/child1` modules, which makes "flattening" all modules not possible.
In `build.sbt` I use names like:

```
val `group-child1` = (project in (file("group/child1")))
val `child1` = (project in (file("child1")))
```

With a flat multi-module structure it would be easy to configure, (but not for my case) :

```
sonar.modules=child1,child2,...
sonar.sources=src/main
sonar.tests=src/test
```

But I need a configuration for deeper nested structure.